# Does EIP 4626 support rebase tokens as underlying asset in the vault?

Tags: eip, compound-protocol

Good day everyone.

I came across a problem while integrating **Compound's cUSDC v3** token as a collateral in my project since the balance is constantly changing due to rebasing. I thought of wrapping it into shares or non-rebasing token (such as wstETH, rETH). How much **EIP 4626** is compatible with reward-earning (rebase) tokens ?